# paho-mqtt in frontend: only logged in users should be able to connect to broker

Tags: security, frontend, mqtt

I am using the paho-mqtt library in my frontend and want to connect to my MQTT Broker which is running on my backend. I created one user account for the broker.
One way to connect to the broker is by using the username, the password and the mqtt.connect(options) function.

But this means that the username and password will be in the frontend in clear text which I have to avoid, because somebody could try to get the username and password somehow and connect to the broker - this should never happen. only users who successfully logged in should be able to connect to the broker.

How can I solve this?

Thanks for your help and all the best,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what broker you are using this is going to be hard to answer. I'm also assuming that when you say frontend you mean a web app and you are using the Paho Javascript client in the page to connect to the broker?

But assuming you are using a broker that supports some sort of authentication plugin/API then it will be trivial to dynamically create a username/token when the user logs into the frontend and using these to authenticate to the broker. The credentials can be passed to the page as part of the login process and used to authenticate the page, when the session expires or the user logs out then you delete these generated credentials rendering them useless.